# I can't create a new project with java language anymore on Android Studio Hedgehog?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio, mobile-development

I downloaded android studio latest version Hedgehog, and I found it strange that there is no longer an option to select JAVA languages on the new project screen. Is this a bug? did I do something wrong? Or is there really no more support for the java language in Hedgehog? How can I resolve this?
Thanks for any help! Unfortunately I didn't find any answer to this problem on the internet.

[image]

I do not know what to do.

Comment: That option is just for the Gradle files. You will still be able to create and use Java classes in your project with that option selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a bug?

No.

> Or is there really no more support for the java language in Hedgehog?

Every Kotlin project can also use Java. All the Java vs. Kotlin choice did before was control whether Kotlin was configured in the project.

> How can I resolve this?

Just create Java classes.

Comment: Yes, correct. Also, this happens when Empty Activity (default is Jetpack Compose), if you select Empty Views Activity, it will have option in the wizard itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can create new project using java language using below steps:

1. Open Android Studio
2. click on new project
3. Select **Empty Views Activity**
4. Click on next button
5. Then select **Java** from **Language** drop down section
6. Then select **Groovy DSL (build.gradle)** from **Build Configuration Language** drop down
7. Now click Finish button.

Answer (score 0):

android studio hedgehog starts with kotlin files but we can still create the java classes. create a new activity and choose the java in source language section.[image: here is the opotions]